# Regex , regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string of the following pattern : 
"x44A-x440-x427-x45E-Yellow-apple", for the hex numbers(of unicode  characters) I want to replace those dashes with # character and to append the # to the first one as well. Those hex codes can be any from the unicode char range.  Please help with the regex to achieve my goal, prefferably in perl. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sounds like you're just giving specification for us to do your work.

Comment: Hi, I'm a very new to regexs, this is where I am at the moment :

my $tt = "x44A-x440-x427-x45E-Yellow-apple";
$tt =~ s/\-[\x00-\xfff]/#/g;

I'm just testing, but it also replaces -Y and -a as well, which is unwanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
s/x([0-9a-fA-F]{1,5})/ chr hex $1 /eg
```

Comment: Hi, thanks much, that worked (need only remove dashes in between). What's the meaning of the {1,5} ?

Comment: 1 to 5 of the previous atom

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To also remove the dashes in between, ikegami's solution could be modified to this.

```
s/(?:^|-)x([0-9a-fA-F]{1,5})/ chr hex $1 /eg;
```

The `(?:^|-)` part says an 'x' at either the beginning of a string or following a dash. `($: ... )` is a non capturing grouping.